# How to continue to support iOS 5.1 as functions became deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that must work for iOS versions >= 5.1.

Apple docs say that "The AudioSession API has been completely deprecated in iOS 7.0". And one should use AVAudioSession class instead.

But the method that I need (`- (BOOL)setCategory:(NSString *)category withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions)options error:(NSError **)outError`) is only available starting from iOS 6.0.

So it seems that I have to continue usage of deprecated `AudioSessionSetProperty` to support iOS 5.1.

What is a correct way to handle such situations (my question is general, not only about this particular problem with audio)? Should I write something like

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    // use deprecated methods (AudioSessionSetProperty)
}
else
{
    // use brand-new methods (AVAudioSession)
}
```

or maybe it's ok to just use `AudioSessionSetProperty` until it stops to compile?

Comment: I'm assuming you do enterprise apps? As Apple will no longer support iOS < 6 come February. Even 6 is fairly minimally used today.

Comment: I would go with first approach that's how we handle the version check as it has an added advantage of visibility where you can see which lines of code need refactoring once you upgrade your deployment version.

Comment: @ahwulf Does it mean that if I have iPad 1st gen (that cannot be upgraded from iOS 5.1), then I would not be able to get any new app on it starting from Feb?

Comment: From the app store, yes I think that is the end result, although Apple does allow you to install older versions of apps. But not an updated one. Other than for enterprise of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated methods doesn't stops you from using it, but yes if its deprecated from your current selected iOS version then it'll give you warning. An example, if your app still supporting iOS < 6.0 and you're need to change alignment of `UILabel` then you can do it like this,

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
    //for iOS < 6.0, warning when deployment target is iOS 5.0
}
else
{
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; //for iOS >= 6.0
}
```

OR

```
lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; //with warning in iOS 6.0
```

OR

```
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; //will crash in iOS 5.0
```

PS. better to support iOS 7.0 and higher (not even iOS 6.0 as Apple wouldn't allow apps with iOS6.0 from coming Feb as commented by @ahwulf.), as latest iOS 8 was released with lots of good features and most of the people updated their phone with this. This will help you in two cases, you'll not need to check for iOS version compatibility and your code looks nice without warnings :) but still its all depends your needs.

Update:

OR

as [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) suggested one should check for existence of method using `respondsToSelector:`

```
UILabel *label;

if([label respondsToSelector:@selector(textAlignment)]) {
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

In above example, we're checking (but in real we're already know this) whether `UILabel` has `textAlignment` property or not.

Comment: Note that numeric comparison of OS versions is not correct. (For example, OS X 10.10 would be sorted incorrectly.) You can use `-[NSProcessInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:]`, except that method itself is new in iOS 8.0 and isn't available on older OS versions.